# XML with varying number of subchildren to data frame/table

Tags: r, xml, xml2

I am trying to transform data from XML to tabular form. I am struggling with elements with subchildren. Here's an example:

```
library(xml2)
library(data.table)

doc =
"<doc>
    <rec>
        <name> John </name>
        <address>
            <street> 2nd Av </street>
            <number> 1036 </number>
        </address>
        <hobbies>
            <hobby> tennis </hobby>
            <hobby> gardening </hobby>    
        </hobbies>
    </rec>
    <rec>
        <name> Mary </name>
        <address>
            <street>55th St</street>
            <number> 132 </number>
        </address>
        <hobbies>
            <hobby> running </hobby>
        </hobbies>
    </rec>
</doc>
"

# read in
pg <- read_xml(doc)

# make a list of records
recs = xml_find_all(pg, "//rec", xml_ns(pg))

# function to loop over list
extractRecord = function(x) {
    
    txt = xml_text(xml_children(x))
    name = xml_name(xml_children(x))
    names(txt) = name
    
    dt = setDT(as.list(txt))[]
    return(dt)
}

# loop over list of records
lst = lapply(recs, extractRecord)

# bind elements do a data table
dt  = rbindlist(lst, use.names = T, fill = T); dt

>      name        address             hobbies
> 1:  John   2nd Av  1036   tennis  gardening 
> 2:  Mary    55th St 132             running
```

This works like a charm, except that I would like to have:

1. two columns for the "address", one for each subelement of  -- say, address.street and address.number.
2. two columns for hobbies -- say hobby1 and hobby2. Important to note that the number of subchildren of  is allowed to vary.

In the end, I'd have something like

[image]

I would aslo like to stick to the `xml2` package if possible (because I have many, large-ish files and the `XML` package has known memory issues that become a problem in my case).

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/) special-purpose, declarative language (same type as SQL) designed to transform XML files such as flattening your original input. In R, XSLT can be run with the sister package to `xml2`: `xslt`. And since it is an industry language, it can be run with other general-purpose languages (i.e., Java, Python), CLIs (Bash, PowerShell), or [executables](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) (Saxon, Xalan) which R can call at command line using `system()`.

```
library(xslt)

xsl <- '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(*)]"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*/*/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>'
```

See: [Online demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWAR/2)

Similar process as before but with transformation step to create *new_pg*:

```
# read in
pg <- read_xml(doc)
style <- read_xml(xsl, package = "xslt")

# transform original
new_pg <- xml_xslt(pg, style)

# make a list of records
recs <- xml_find_all(new_pg, "//rec")

# function to loop over list
extractRecord <- function(x) {      
  txt <- setNames(xml_text(xml_children(x)), 
                  xml_name(xml_children(x))
         )

  dt <- setDT(as.list(txt))[]
  return(dt)
}

# loop over list of records
lst <- lapply(recs, extractRecord)

# bind elements do a data table
dt <- rbindlist(lst, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
dt
#     name   street number     hobby       hobby
# 1:  John   2nd Av   1036    tennis   gardening 
# 2:  Mary  55th St    132   running        <NA>
```

To avoid repeating columns (i.e., *hobby*) add this template at the end of XSLT (before closing `</xsl:stylesheet>`) where you can pipe delimit any other columns you know in advance will have repeating columns:

```
  <!-- PIPE DELIMIT ANY REPEAT NAMED COLS IN TEMPLATE MATCH-->
  <xsl:template match="hobby|anothernode|othernode|stillothernode">
    <xsl:variable name="num" select="concat(name(), count(preceding-sibling::*)+1)"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$num}">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:element>  
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Very nice, I did not know `xslt`. Does it handle large (ie., with many records, on the 100s of Mb ballpark) XML files well? The only thing that puts me off is (like in @JasonAizkalns' answer above) having to enumerate every single field to be extracted. I am amazed there's no out-of-the-shelf solution for my question.

Comment: XSLT is great for small to mid-100 MBs. Over 1 GB, it runs into memory issues since it must read entire XML file and parse. Not clear what you mean every single field. The same code you set up is being run here, namely all children of *rec* node.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait. By every single field, I mean the following. Imagine that besides name, address, and hobbies, I had another 50 types of tags per record (which will become 50 additional columns-or fields- in the tabular format) also with subchildren. In your solution, you hard coded the fields with subchildren for parsing. With many more elements like this, it becomes a bit of a pain.

Comment: See update XSLT where no node is hard-coded but assumes a three-level only XML. However, the challenge is same named columns like *hobby* will repeat without # suffix. You can clean up on backend in R or add another XSLT template (see note at end) which will be only hard-coded item which hopefully you can know in advance and is limited in number.

Answer (score 0):

So if you're open to using the `tidyverse` here's an approach. First change your function to extract all the data for an *individual* record:

```
library(tidyverse)

get_elements <- function(rec) {

  name = xml_find_all(rec, "name") %>% xml_text

  hobbies = xml_find_all(rec, "hobbies")
  hobby_list = hobbies %>% xml_find_all("hobby") %>% xml_text

  address = xml_find_all(rec, "address")
  street = address %>% xml_find_all("street") %>% xml_text
  street_num = address %>% xml_find_all("number") %>% xml_text

  df = tibble(
    name = str_squish(name),
    street = str_squish(street), 
    street_num = str_squish(street_num),
    hobbies = str_squish(hobby_list)
  )
  return(df)
}
```

So now, for any given record (e.g. `recs[1]`, `recs[2]`) we return a table:

```
get_elements(recs[1])
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   name  street street_num hobbies  
#>   <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1 John  2nd Av 1036       tennis   
#> 2 John  2nd Av 1036       gardening
get_elements(recs[2])
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   name  street  street_num hobbies
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  
#> 1 Mary  55th St 132        running
```

Then combined those tables using your favorite method:

```
res_df <- 
bind_rows(
  get_elements(recs[1]),
  get_elements(recs[2])
)

# More tidyverse/purrr-like:
res_df <- 
  recs %>%
  map_df(get_elements)

res_df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   name  street  street_num hobbies  
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>    
#> 1 John  2nd Av  1036       tennis   
#> 2 John  2nd Av  1036       gardening
#> 3 Mary  55th St 132        running
```

Finally, do some data wrangling to pivot the data into the desired final format:

```
res_df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(
    hobby_idx = paste0("hobby", row_number())
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = hobby_idx,
    values_from = hobbies
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#> # Groups:   name [2]
#>   name  street  street_num hobby1  hobby2   
#>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>    
#> 1 John  2nd Av  1036       tennis  gardening
#> 2 Mary  55th St 132        running <NA>
```

Comment: I see two issues with this approach. First, searching for each tag (name, hobbies, address, etc) can be burdensome in large data. Now I see I should have been more explicit about this in my OP. Second, and more importantly, if a record has no hobbies (as I said in OP, the number varies), the whole record is "lost", i.e., the code returns a tibble with 0 rows.